# "[ERROR] duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF" shows up when using IntelliGuard to compile

Tags: java

I'm trying to use IntelliGuard plugin in IntelliJ to compile and obfuscate my jar file, but "[ERROR] duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
" shows up when I try to build in the "Build -> Obfuscate module" window

I am currently using Java 8 with language level of 8.
I tried the normal IntelliJ build artifacts, it worked.
In IntelliGuard, I tried to toggle the "Execute 'make'" button, tried not to set a main class, tried to link libraries in manifest, and it didn't work.
I had setup yguard correctly, so it's probably not the problem with the yguard installation.

Expected:
It should compile and give me a obfuscated jar file

Actual:
[ERROR] duplicate entry: META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

Answer (score 0):

I had same error using  IntellijGuard and then IntellijGuard2 plugin .
First off, achieve to create an executable jar. Then in 'Build' --> 'Obfuscate module'   dialog remove 'module compile output'(each time) and add your root package folder' by navigation to src. E.g. for 'src>your.project.folders' it would be 'your'
Then assign paths for several of jar and obfuscatedf jar to desired location.
Press Build and you'll get obfuscated source files with proguard mapped auto-manifest.
Open obfuscated jar with zip. Remove  auto-manifest and add unzipped libs and META-INF folder with manifest from your project manually.
Now the jar has to  run.